# how to trim the dataframe using ranks in python and reshape them in a new dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

hi I have data frame as below 
my df

```
MobileNumber    Item     score    rank
999999999       a        45       1
999999999       b        44       2
999999999       c        43       3
999999999       d        42       4
888888888       h        65       1
888888888       t        54       2
888888888       yy       43       3
888888888       h        32       4
```

now I want to groupby mobile number and from rank 1 to 3 in my data set I have 40 ranks for each mobilenumber so I need to trim of them as I need only top 3 ranks 
expected output :-

```
 MobileNumber    Item        
    999999999       a,b,c 
    888888888       h.t.yy
```

can any one help me with this

Answer (score 2):

let us use `query` filter before `groupby`

```
df.query('rank<=3').groupby('MobileNumber').Item.apply(','.join)
Out[29]: 
MobileNumber
888888888    h,t,yy
999999999     a,b,c
Name: Item, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have ordered `rank`s already, just get `head(3)` to get top 3.

```
df.groupby('MobileNumber')['Item'].agg(lambda s: ','.join(s.head(3)))
```

---

```
MobileNumber
888888888    h,t,yy
999999999     a,b,c
Name: Item, dtype: object
```